# See if a rowkey exists in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hbase

In HBase there's a HTable.exists(Get) method that allows me to see if a rowkey has (at least) one cell associated. What about Cassandra? It seems there's no such corresponding feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a request for one column.  If anything is returned, the row exists.

For example, in pycassa you would do:

```
if column_family.get(key, column_count=1):
    print key, "exists"
```

Through CQL 3, depending on your schema, you would just do a simple select like:

```
SELECT * FROM mycf WHERE key = 'foo'
```